# Collaborate using git and separate branches without adding a bunch of redundant commits

Tags: git, github, collaboration, git-workflow

I'm collaborating with a designer on a project called "Verified Accounts"

I'm developing on a branch called `verified_accounts` and the designer is on a branch called `chris_verified_accounts`. We've been periodically merging each other's changes, and when the project is done we'll merge `verified_accounts` into `master`

However, all this merging has been causing a bunch of junk / duplicative commits. For example:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2012-03-02_1024.png

Commit (1) is a merge of a pull request that contains only commit (2). This means that these commits are essentially identical (they have the same diffs, etc). Likewise, commit (3) is a merge that merges only commit (4), meaning 3 and 4 are also essentially identical

What's the best way to manage these identical commits? I.e., for each functional change in my code I want one associated commit. This way if I'm commenting on a change set I can be sure I'm commenting in the right place (versus commenting on the exactly-similar change set of another dupe-y commit)

What's the best practice for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3):

Since you merge you get merge commits, which is unavoidable when you are merging branches. What you could do instead is to pull and rebase at the same time:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Comment: So instead of `git pull chris_verified_accounts && git checkout verified_accounts && git merge chris_verified_accounts` I'd do `git checkout verified_accounts && git pull chris_verified_accounts --rebase`? How would this make the history look?

Comment: Try it and see for yourself :)

Comment: You can always undo with git. When in doubt, commit! As long as code have been commited you can undo anything. If the pull --rebase doesn't work properly for some reason (only thing that can really happen is that you get a conflict and you mess up when resolving the conflict) you can always undo with "git reset --hard HEAD" if you want to undo the conflict and "git reset --hard HEAD^" if you want to undo a solved conflict that has gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to see these commits as what they are: merge commits. There are not simply “duplicate commits.” (In fact, they are not duplicate commits at all.) They contain the information that a branch was merged into another. When you try to have a linear history (which — lets face it — is a relict of systems that couldn’t handle branching and especially merging in a sane way) you inevitably lose information about how your source code came into being the way it is now. Merge commits are an important part of your project’s history, allowing you to see which commits belonged to which branch at which point in time. It allows you to follow each branch even years after you have written them. If there’s anything fishy in a commit you can use that context information to re-understand why you did it that way.

Please don’t artificially hobble your repository by trying to have it look nice in some visualization tool. Try to harness the full power of branching and merging.

(Yes, I love Git. And branches. And merging.)

Comment: I'm fine with a commit that contains *only* the information that a merge happened. But this is not how it works - these merge commits ALSO contain the changeset (at least when I view them on Github). This is DEFINITELY wrong behavior because it duplicates information and leaves the user with uncertainty as to where he should comment on a given change – in the diff of the commit in which it was introduced, or the merge commit?

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. Github is cheating on you. Try `git show -p <commit-id>` and you will see that a commit does not contain any changes; it is merely a commit with two parent commits. (That is at least valid for merges without conflict. I’m not quite sure how Git handles merges with conflicts.)